# a working GMap.NET application source

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm using GMap for the first time, but my maps won't show... I'm looking for a working a c# application source. Can you help me?

Note: I've downloaded [this](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/releases/view/20235#DownloadId=67818) and [this](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/releases/view/20235#DownloadId=51274) file from http://greatmaps.codeplex.com, but they are just applications, and no source included...

Thanks.

Comment: greatmaps.net is on codeplex so it has sources available: http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets#

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is form with `gMapControl1` on it. Add reference on `Gmap.NET.Core` and `Gmap.NET.WindowsForms` to your project.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GMap.NET.MapProviders;
using GMap.NET;

namespace gmap
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //use google provider
            gMapControl1.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
            //get tiles from server only
            gMapControl1.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
            //not use proxy
            GMapProvider.WebProxy = null;
            //center map on moscow
            gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(55.755786121111, 37.617633343333);

            //zoom min/max; default both = 2
            gMapControl1.MinZoom = 1;
            gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 20;
            //set zoom
            gMapControl1.Zoom = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no map shows: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JYBnK.png

Comment: sorry about that. Set `gMapControl.Zoom` to 1.

Comment: WOW! Thanks... But I see just a World map... it doesn't go to the position...

Comment: It's centered on position (red cross). Change zoom and you see.

Comment: Here I add few lines about zoom. It's make example more interesting.