# Is it possible to open Google Maps via C# Windows Forms Applications? Not a site, but only the map

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There is a lot of answers about Google Maps in C#, but I didn't found any correct for me. The question is: I need to open the whole browser to look at the map? Or, maybe, I can open just a map in any previously defined coordinates using Google Maps API? Maybe I can use GMAP for it? I am newbie and I don't know what to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547147/a-working-gmap-net-application-source and http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/

Comment: Can I avoid third-party .net's?

Comment: You can try to show in a web browser control only the maps frame and not whole google maps page. Look at this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Comment: ElmoDev001, thank you! I guess, that's the stuff.